# Flutter: How to drag points on a plot

Tags: flutter, dart

I am still relatively new to flutter and building a app that can allow user to drag points on a xy plane by holding the point and dragging it.( e.g dragging a point at (1 ,1) to (2,3) )

Did not come across any libraries/packages that can do this function. So was wondering if this would be possible ? Much thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are looking for [`Draggable`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Draggable-class.html).

Example from doc

```dart
class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  int acceptedData = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: <Widget>[
        Draggable<int>(
          // Data is the value this Draggable stores.
          data: 10,
          feedback: Container(
            color: Colors.deepOrange,
            height: 100,
            width: 100,
            child: const Icon(Icons.directions_run),
          ),
          childWhenDragging: Container(
            height: 100.0,
            width: 100.0,
            color: Colors.pinkAccent,
            child: const Center(
              child: Text('Child When Dragging'),
            ),
          ),
          child: Container(
            height: 100.0,
            width: 100.0,
            color: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
            child: const Center(
              child: Text('Draggable'),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        DragTarget<int>(
          builder: (
            BuildContext context,
            List<dynamic> accepted,
            List<dynamic> rejected,
          ) {
            return Container(
              height: 100.0,
              width: 100.0,
              color: Colors.cyan,
              child: Center(
                child: Text('Value is updated to: $acceptedData'),
              ),
            );
          },
          onAccept: (int data) {
            setState(() {
              acceptedData += data;
            });
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```